# Adding a button intent within fragments, tabs, actionbarsherlock

Tags: android-intent, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-button

I am working on an app that implements tabs in the action bar using fragments and actionbarsherlock. One of my fragment class has buttons. When i click on the buttons I want to initiate an activity(load browser to go to the url or start another app) I am hard pressed to find any info on this dealing with fragments. I have come across information on implementing this with activities. 
My first question is where does the button code go... MainActivity? Or my fragment class? Second, does actionbarsherlock have anything to do with it? Third, does the manifest file need to be updated?

Thanks in advance. Also forgive my lack of code talk. Working with a beginner here haha

This is one of my fragment tabs with the buttons. If i need to post the MainActivity code let me know.

```
public class SoTab extends SherlockFragment {

@Override
public SherlockFragmentActivity getSherlockActivity() {
    return super.getSherlockActivity();
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        }
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    setUserVisibleHint(true);
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sotab, container, false);


    return view;

      }

}
```